# Model fitting doesn't work (logistic)

Tags: maximum-likelihood, python, fitting, curve-fitting

I try to fit logistic model to my data. However, I don't know what is happening that results seem wrong. Graphic doesn't work as expect.

Here is what I expect as result:[image]

Here is my code:

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import pylab as py    

xdata = np.array(170.53999999999999, 200.34, 292.79000000000002, 
295.88, 309.20999999999998, 309.47000000000003, 311.63, 
314.70999999999998, 334.87, 338.72000000000003, 351.31999999999999, 
353.88999999999999, 374.80000000000001, 377.94, 378.52999999999997, 
382.94, 387.95999999999998, 391.94999999999999, 400.56, 
417.52999999999997, 420.94, 422.13999999999999, 435.08999999999997, 
464.63999999999999, 464.68000000000001, 467.94, 474.42000000000002, 
491.5, 492.31, 494.48000000000002, 514.13, 522.91999999999996, 
527.54999999999995, 540.72000000000003, 547.29999999999995, 
551.20000000000005, 561.0, 563.39999999999998, 568.04999999999995, 
568.13999999999999, 570.34000000000003, 580.89999999999998, 
585.91999999999996, 586.50999999999999, 593.86000000000001, 
596.45000000000005, 601.41999999999996, 603.73000000000002, 
605.10000000000002, 617.66999999999996, 619.38999999999999, 
623.83000000000004, 640.20000000000005, 646.80999999999995, 
660.17999999999995, 662.63, 664.29999999999995, 666.76999999999998, 
670.00999999999999, 683.01999999999998, 685.45000000000005, 
707.11000000000001, 709.34000000000003, 729.66999999999996, 
731.21000000000004, 738.15999999999997, 746.39999999999998, 
748.72000000000003, 754.13999999999999, 756.35000000000002, 
757.15999999999997, 759.25999999999999, 765.00999999999999, 
786.46000000000004, 805.49000000000001, 811.10000000000002, 
814.57000000000005, 826.65999999999997, 827.19000000000005, 
841.86000000000001, 843.77999999999997, 845.69000000000005, 
856.89999999999998, 900.63999999999999, 916.5, 82.280000000000001, 
170.53999999999999, 172.84999999999999, 211.97999999999999, 222.22, 
233.19999999999999, 244.88, 265.06, 301.97000000000003, 
320.72000000000003, 322.36000000000001, 334.87, 344.88, 
361.58999999999997, 378.66000000000003, 416.94, 430.23000000000002, 
430.33999999999997, 435.08999999999997, 462.17000000000002, 
465.83999999999997, 470.04000000000002, 493.31, 496.48000000000002, 
499.25, 504.87, 513.22000000000003, 521.04999999999995, 
535.10000000000002, 557.10000000000002, 580.89999999999998, 609.87, 
614.92999999999995, 628.69000000000005, 630.13999999999999, 
660.57000000000005, 661.00999999999999, 726.94000000000005, 
728.32000000000005, 730.65999999999997, 758.76999999999998, 
767.23000000000002, 856.38)

ydata = np.array(438.09599331812927, 537.23256297037005, 
19269.370060543995, 12410.496093814729, 401.8733029444702, 
10967.013002847321, 20282.057861481328, 26147.769626987865, 
2798.6708979485561, 30635.176025749184, 16902.449558314398, 
50205.130818114616, 16833.476577291731, 37632.457219207659, 
4832.2872499506921, 49756.175845809747, 16210.963994871823, 
46300.627152966335, 11792.361924481576, 1133.8675242853349, 
26765.88074381277, 1575.0296080997214, 14288.834664244669, 
40293.888858807739, 950.42491144151438, 1452.9234368011819, 
37443.101996814374, 8556.2340741392691, 24586.112539105587, 
13011.290302406996, 7295.7725339331664, 10681.313170841429, 
23594.300440669991, 33430.238604378887, 32982.915818345267, 
22172.459371404257, 5567.6812170930216, 65000.176281097811, 
41483.146954813514, 7978.2917736168019, 24403.250355317723, 
873.20409517874941, 30858.4043755536, 52752.141929424368, 
12650.456280176992, 23987.113995570224, 28591.013878939208, 
20407.911440353371, 13445.105672593694, 21920.24338372238, 
2690.861246606335, 25798.110032560304, 35980.649282796316, 
492.51588408462709, 32086.10909153102, 51844.02730442211, 
10969.811241999267, 533.57266898360103, 66128.050330224913, 
4666.599467351567, 61887.026568667025, 2902.798437214457, 
22848.87543264544, 13822.767501054796, 33038.978412663564, 
27987.236212885942, 18110.242457594723, 433.27264334959915, 
56132.973488457501, 40083.172147933394, 12454.655498179607, 
46491.505261648446, 42572.336754649412, 38843.917322065681, 
39429.178997456562, 44776.225260119412, 7092.2030675862916, 
12964.252199171111, 43372.884538894985, 1638.8421535226514, 
12026.04034807533, 43961.004976233933, 2208.5979545717128, 
6914.1765586384572, 2592.4781003650282, 9634.3589108451288, 
2733.0136844511144, 2467.029004312586, 14825.811965473227, 
2466.1513173554558, 917.56925152405165, 4654.396552776685, 
1358.7775281236973, 13821.628596086754, 6286.4916925411671, 
1142.4245911829639, 8057.9356143986806, 3925.0099971210579, 
313.4867529268376, 37412.56948946137, 14885.923665301641, 
80957.185252863666, 3887.3285083221272, 6795.0325982165514, 
2557.8215322191832, 739.99086352600727, 9597.6796023598872, 
34667.162666805554, 627.76766225136828, 19399.158335053358, 
578.84516647318378, 2218.9537470918149, 4216.9877868359908, 
33189.097161883721, 5621.6260880785985, 278.4729612825904, 
51453.352322823135, 3846.3000632636249, 1479.6505662589334, 
16996.093153429683, 1618.5265271833634, 36473.774729755241, 
8202.0762869447935, 2218.4113809545524, 535.38385538337752, 
2690.448623833945, 6983.9278990463354, 4010.8227603668347)

def sigmoid(params):
    k = params[0]
    x0 = params[1]
    sd = params[2]

    yPred = 1 / (1+ np.exp(-k*(xdata-x0)))

    # Calculate negative log likelihood
    LL = -np.sum(stats.norm.logpdf(ydata, loc=yPred, scale=sd))

    return(LL)


initParams = [1, 1, 1]

results = minimize(sigmoid, initParams, method='BFGS')
print(results.x)

estParms = results.x
yOut = yPred = 1 / (1+ np.exp(-estParms[0]*(xdata-estParms[1])))

py.clf()
py.plot(xdata,ydata, 'go')
py.plot(xdata, yOut)
py.show()
```

Comment: It looks like your xdata is the same as your ydata.  Please verify the posted data.

Comment: Yeahhh. My goodness! You are right. I will correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A logistic model assumes that your $y$ data is binary (zeros and ones), and attempts to approximate $P(y = 1 \mid x)$ with a sigmoid curve like:

$$ P(y = 1 \mid x) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{- \beta_0 + \beta_1 x}} $$

The value of the function on the right hand side cannot be larger than one.

Your data is not binary.  You are attempting to fit a sigmoid curve through continuous data with range much larger than zero to one, so you are attempting to fit a model to data that the model cannot hope to approximate.  To do this you will have to use a non-linear least squares model, and add an additional scaling factor to your model

$$ \hat y = \frac{c}{1 + e^{- \beta_0 + \beta_1 x}} $$

Comment: Can you send me some material that I read?